# How to mock injected dependency for flutter widget test

Tags: flutter, dart, mocking

I have a back button which we are using to pop to previous screen. The onPressedEvent has a dependency injection which helps you to go back to previous screen. How can I mock this dependency for the widget test in flutter?

```
class BackButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const BackButton({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomButton(
      label:'Back',
      icon: Icon.arrowLeft,
      onPressed: inject<CustomRouter>().pop,
    );
  }
}
```

I get the below error whenever I try to run the widget test.

```
Did you forget to register it?)
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
Failed assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using mocktail (https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail).

Mocked class

```
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class MockFooClass extends Mock implements FooClass {}
```

Test class

```
testWidgets('MyTest', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    ...
    final FooClass fooClass = MockFooClass();
    final getIt = GetIt.instance;
    getIt.registerSingleton<FooClass>(fooClass);
    when(() => fooClass.barMethod).thenAnswer((_) => something?);
    ...
});
```